# Will Apache2 restart if I reboot whole ubuntu

Tags: apache2

When I restart apache2 it gives me error:

```
Restarting web server apache2 (98)
Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:3000
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
```

So I'm considering If I reboot the whole ubuntu will it get restarted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will, but your error will still exist as well. Go find apache2.conf and ports.conf, and update your question with the section that states which ports you are listening on. `locate apache2.conf`  also: `locate ports.conf`

I'm guessing, your ports file or config files are screwed up, and preventing apache2 from running. Post back with port info from both files.